# Firestore: How to update a document's field that is a document reference?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using firestore with AngularFire 2 and one of my fields a reference to a different document.

I'm able to use this field in my angular app, but: How do I update this field?

I'm trying creating a new `AngularFirestoreDocument` pointing to the correct reference but I'm getting:

> DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom AngularFirestoreDocument object`

```
public updateConfig(newConfig: ConfigId) {
    const preset: AngularFirestoreDocument<Config> = this.db.doc<Config>('/reference/path');
    this.businessDoc.update({'config': preset})
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was simple, but it took a deep dive into firebase. Just add `.ref` to your `AngularFirestoreDocument`

```
public updateConfig(newConfig: ConfigId) {
    const preset: AngularFirestoreDocument<Config> = this.db.doc<Config>('/presets/' + newConfig.id);
    this.businessDoc.update({'config': preset.ref})
}
```